# Reveal a picture above another one with a circular mask on mouse move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 images on top of each other. First it is showing only the lower one. When hovering above the lower-image, it should reveal the upper-image in a circular mask (preferable with a gradient) - similar effect to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/xaviDDB/pen/ExaKeeN).

The difference to the codepen is that the images are not fixed background images but "normal" relative-positioned images. The idea was to have a div container in the shape of a circle with the upper-image inside, which is absolute-positioned. The circle-div should follow the cursor when above the lower-image and should therefore reveal parts of the upper-image. Both images should not move their positions - only the circle-div should move.

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="lower-image" src="lower.png" width="1920" height="1280">

    <div class="circle"> 
        <img id="upper-image" src="upper.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#upper-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```
(function() {
    let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
    let circleHalf = circle.offsetWidth / 2;
  
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
        circle.style.left = e.pageX - circleHalf+'px';
        circle.style.top = e.pageY - circleHalf+'px';
    });
})();
```

The problem is that the circle-div moves the absolute-positioned upper-image and therefore it is only showing the same part of the upper-image, no matter the position of the cursor.

Comment: go to this [codePen](https://codepen.io/xaviDDB/pen/ExaKeeN) and set `background-image: url('image.jpeg'); background-size: cover;` for `.container{}` css class. i think this is worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the nesting of the code, here is a working version:

```
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('image1')">
    <div class="circle" style="background-image: url('img2')" > 
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    height: 40rem;
    width: 40rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 10rem);
    left: calc(50% - 10rem);
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background: center center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Your current js works great

Live code: https://jsfiddle.net/6z80owta/25/

If you would like to add a gradient to the circle, add this pseudo element:

```
.circle::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgb(0, 0, 0));
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I want both pictures to be relative positioned. In your case the picture with the human is a fixed background image, which is wrong. Both pictures should be scrollable and on top of each other. Otherwise you got it right.